# React add array to state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React. In my state, I am trying to have an empty array initialized to store polygons.

The structure I want to have is an array like  `this.state.polyList = [[dot1,dot2,dot3...],[dot1,dot2,dot3...]]`

I am trying to have a

```
let newState = Object.assign({},this.state);
let newValue = [points]; // "points" is [dot1,dot2,dot3...]
console.log(newValue[0][0]); // able to print correctly
newState.polyList = newState.polyList.concat(newValue)
this.setState(newState)
```

However, when I later log the `state.polyList`, I only have a few empty array ([]) inside list

Comment: Since your state is nested, you need to do a deep clone to properly copy your state to prevent state mutation. `Object.assign()` doesn't do a deep clone.

Answer (score 1):

You can add like this array to state array

```
 state = {
    items: [4,5,6],
  };
```

function to add

```
  handleClick = e => {
  this.setState({
   items:[...this.state.items,[Math.floor(Math.random()*100),7,8]]
   })
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to something like below.

```
let newValue = [points]; // "points" is [dot1,dot2,dot3...]
console.log(newValue[0][0]); // able to print correctly

let newState = { ...this.state, 
                 polyList: [...this.state.polyList, newValue] };

this.setState(newState)
```

Answer (score 0):

Deep cloning in `react` doesn't work the way you are doing. A way that i prefer to use is by `spread` operator. You can do something like:

```
let newState = [...this.state.polyList];
newState.push(points)
this.setState({ polyList: newState });
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Since an array is a reference type he is assigning the value even after he does concatenation `newState.polyList = newState.polyList.concat(newValue)` so that may not be the exact reason. Deep Clone might be as mentioned in the comments by jayce.

Comment: @Ramesh Yes, you are right. I will update my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this would be is structuring.

```
let oldState = [1,2,4]

this.setState ([...oldState, [new state array]])
```

Comment: thanks for noting. But it is still not working. The list turns to be all filled with empty arrays.